# How to get checkbox list value and display in another form (angular 4)

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

This is my coding which is HTML and TS. I fetch checkbox value from Database using code this.service.initCompany.

```js
**This is my TS file**

this.form = formBuilder.group({
        company: [''],
      });
      

//I populate checklist Company from Database
    initCategoriesCompany() {
        this.service.initCompany(this.language)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data.results);

            for (var x = 0; x < data.results.length; x++) {
              let category = new CompanyModel();
                category.companyProviderId = this.hexMaskPipe.transform(data.results[x]['hex(companyCategoryId)'],'hex', true);
                      category.code = data.results[x].code;
                      category.description = data.results[x]['desc_'+this.language];
                      this.categoriesCompany.push(category);
                  
          }
              console.log(this.categoriesCompany);
              });
          }
```

```html
**This is my HTML file**

<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group row">
            <label class="form-control-label col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-12" for="category">Pembekal Syarikat </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-12">
              <ul class="list-unstyled sub-list-tree">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categoriesCompany; let row=index;">
                  <li class="mb-q">
                    <span class="sub-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="{{category.code}}" value="{{category.code}}" formControlName="company" (change)="change($event, category.description)"/>
                      {{category.description | uppercase}}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                </ng-container>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
 </form>

**I want to display value from checkbox when checked here**
 
 <!--I want to display checklist value here which is in another form-->
<div class="form-group row" >
          <label class="form-control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-12"> Syarikat</label>
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-12">{{ company[description] | uppercase }}</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: stackblitz.com is very quick for Angular4 code... if you can update it their, it;ll be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

at First you have a list of items on form and you have to define the formcontrol as array

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
        company: this.formBuilder.array([{}])
      });
```

Now, on component TS file you have create a variable where you put the checked values.

```
let selectedCompony = {};

onchange(companyObj){
   this.selectedCompony = companyObj;
}
```

and then you can use the created variable in

```
 <!--I want to display checklist value here which is in another form-->
<div class="form-group row" >
          <label class="form-control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-12"> Syarikat</label>
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-12">{{ company.description | uppercase }}</div>
        </div>
```